# How can I pass values between Activities on Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

This is the navigation of my application:

> `Activity1` calls `Activity2` → `Activity2.finish()`, call `Activity3` → `Activity3.finish()`

When `Activity3` finishes, it calls the `onResume` method of `Activity1`. Now how can I pass a value from `Activity3` to `Activity1`?

Comment: [this link for another way to pass the data activity3 to activity1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42268095/7399521)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Umesh shows a good technique but I think you want the opposite direction.

**Step 1**

When starting Activity 2 and 3, use `startActivityForResult`. This allows you handle the result in the calling activity.

```
startActivityForResult(MY_REQUEST_ID);
```

**Step 2**

In Activities 2 and 3, call `setResult(int, Intent)` to return a value:

```
Intent resultData = new Intent();
resultData.putExtra("valueName", "valueData");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);
finish();
```

**Step 3**

In your calling activty, implement `onActivityResult` and get the data:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
          Intent data) {
      if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_ID) {
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String myValue = data.getStringExtra("valueName"); 
            // use 'myValue' return value here
          }
      }
}
```

**Edit:**

**Technique #2**

Yes, you can also use global application state by adding a class to your application that extends `Application`, see this StackOverflow **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)**

Comment: I can't use this method , because activity2 it's finish and activity3 can't return value to activity1.There isn't variable with application scope?

Comment: Yes you can return Activity 3 value to Activity 2, then return Actiivty same value from activity 2 to Activity 1.  Just pass it along both levels.  But you are correct, there is another technique to use the android Application base class to store global application state.  See my edit for details

Answer (score 2):

Use the session id to the signout activity in the intent you're using to start the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
startActivity(intent)
```

See this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why even bother following that kind of structure... if three returns to one? Just send an intent with your data from three to one and handle it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Sending an Intent from activity 3 to 1 would require some trigger like a button or perhaps the onStop lifecycle method to send it. Better to have the result be automatically send with the setResult method.

Answer (score 0):

Also there is other technique, you can call  `startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity1.class))` method along with the Bundle class to transfer data from activity3 to activity1.

Answer (score 0):

On Android it is possible to launch another app of a specified *package name*, passing an **argument** to it.

```
public static void launchApp(Context context, String packageName) {
    Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

    if(intent == null) {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
    }
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "*argument to send*");
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

The code below can be used to retrieve the **argument** in the target app.

```
public static String getArgument(Activity activity) {
    return activity.getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
}
```

Only a reference to Activity is needed, this is useful in Unity where it is messy to subclass Activity.