# Send String from Activty to ListFragment (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have my MyActivity that contains three fragments: 1 ListFragment (`listFragmentTest`) and 2 Fragments.
My `listFragmentTest` contains a button. If the user click on this button it will be launched a new activity (`activityTest`).
This `activityTest` contains an EditText Field, where the user can enter a title.

After click on the Button "Save" (in the `activityTest`) I want to send the String "title" to the `listFragmentTest` and show the title in an EditText Field of my `listFragmentTest`.

Here is the code from my activityTest for the button:

```
public void buttonSaveTitle(){
    saveButtonTitleToFragment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button_title_to_fragment);
    saveButtonTitleToFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText editTextTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_title_activity);
            String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
            //And here: Send the String to the listFragment
        }
    });
}
```

I'm new to android development and I tried it with intent and bundle, but without a solution.

---

**EDIT**:

I cannot use `findFragmentById`. The ListFragment has no Id, because it's only a Tab. I've searched and find that I've to set the tag with `FragmentTransaction.add`. But I don't know where I have to insert the `FragmentTransaction.add` in my project.
Or is there another solution without using an id or tag?

Answer (score 0):

Find Fragment using Id or TAG, Then call a defined method.

Such as:

```
  MyFragment myFrag = (MyFragment)
                      getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment);
myFrag.updateString(string);
```

updateString will be a method that you've defined yourself in the fragment to update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5852965/4874829). It uses `startActivityAsResult` and `setResult` to send data back.

Answer (score 0):

Start the `activityTest` as starting it as a result and send the data back to previous `Activity`.

```
int REQUEST_TITLE = 12345;

private void pickTitle() {
    Intent pickTitleIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, activityTest.class);
    startActivityForResult(pickTitleIntent, REQUEST_TITLE);
}
```

In your `activityTest` do this when done

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("title", title);
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

In your `activityTest` listen for result and update your fragment

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TITLE ) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           // Get the string
           String title = data.getString("title");
           MyFragment myFrag = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment);
           myFrag.updateTitle(title);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! :)
I don't understand the line `if (requestCode == ENTER_TITLE)`. What I should enter instead of "ENTER_TITLE"?

Comment: Sorry. REQUEST_TITLE ... or name it whatever you want. It's just an int. I suggest you make a class RequestCodes and put it in as a public static so you can access it everywhere. Make sure the value is the same when you request and when you get the result

Comment: Thanks! I will try your version now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put bundle in Fragment

```
MyFragmentClass mFrag = new MyFragmentClass();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("somekey", "someValue");   
mFrag.setArguments(bundle);

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.someFrag, mFrag).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) in Fragment

```
MyFragmentClass mFrag = new MyFragmentClass();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("somekey", "someValue");   
mFrag.setArguments(bundle);

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.someFrag, mFrag).commit();
```

To retrieve value from bundle

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
String val = bundle.getString("someValue", "");
```