# how to pass intent from 1st activity to second to third activity and viceversa?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 3 activities : activity "valider" as 1st activity and the second is activivty "connexion" and finally the inscription activity , i hope to pass from 1st==> second==> third and viceversa from third==> second==>first activity.
Please someone can help me?

Comment: What is your question actuallly? Please explain in detail.

Comment: Use `Intent` to open from 1 to 2 to 3 , `startActivityForResult` for the viceversa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: I'm using startActivityForResult  but not change

Comment: @ferjaouiwissal you should post your code then

Comment: thank u for your help , i found the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass values between Activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852677/how-can-i-pass-values-between-activities-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to share data with different activities your question is repeated please check this: [What's the best way to share data between activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities)

Answer (score 0):

To pass data in the `First`:

```
void send() {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
intent.putExtra("NAME",some_value);//your data
startActivityForResult(intent, yourSomeId);// if you want to retrieve callback data later
startActivity(intent);//or simply
}
```

in the `Second`
in

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        yourData = null;
    } else {
        yourData = extras.getString("NAME");
    }
}
```

to send data back:

charge data in the second activity:

```
void back() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("NAME", yourdata);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

and retrieve in the First:

```
 @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data == null) {return;}
    yourdata = data.getStringExtra("NAME");

  }
```

you can send the data to the third activity in the same way.